# Keras metric for multiple outputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a keras model with 1 input and 2 outputs.

To evaluate the model, my metric requires `output_1`, `true_y_1` as well as `output2` and `true_y_2`, as it is a complex metric that requires the use of both outputs.

Is there a way to define such metric?

I tried:

```py
def cool_metric(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args)
    print(kwargs)

model.compile(
    loss={
        'output_1': 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
        'output_2': None
    },
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(FLAGS.learning_rate),
    metrics=cool_metric,
)
```

And I get a print of `args` containing 2 arguments alone, `output_1` and `true_y_1`.

Comment: did u evaluate the usage of a custom callback to do this?

Comment: I did not manage to figure out how to make a custom callback work for this. Could you please give an example where a custom callback gets both outputs?

Comment: below I added an example

Answer (score 1):

here an example where I used a callback to compute a custom metric that uses 1 input and 2 outputs

```
class CoolCallback(Callback):
    def __init__(self, train_data, val_data=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.train_data = train_data
        self.val_data = val_data

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
                        
        X = self.train_data[0] # 1 input
        y1, y2 = self.train_data[1] # 2 targets
        y_pred1, y_pred2 = self.model.predict(X) # 2 predictions
                
        error1 = np.mean(np.square(y2-y_pred1))
        error2 = np.mean(np.square(y1-y_pred2))
        
        score = error1 + error2
        
        logs['Cool_score'] = np.round(score, 5)
        
        if self.val_data:
            
            X = self.val_data[0] # 1 input
            y1, y2 = self.val_data[1] # 2 targets
            y_pred1, y_pred2 = self.model.predict(X) # 2 predictions

            error1 = np.mean(np.square(y2-y_pred1))
            error2 = np.mean(np.square(y1-y_pred2))

            score = error1 + error2
            
            logs['Cool_score_val'] = np.round(score, 5)

        

X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (1000,10))
y1 = np.random.uniform(0,1, 1000)
y2 = np.random.uniform(0,1, 1000)

X_val = np.random.uniform(0,1, (1000,10))
y1_val = np.random.uniform(0,1, 1000)
y2_val = np.random.uniform(0,1, 1000)

inp = Input((10,))
x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(inp)
out1 = Dense(1)(x)
out2 = Dense(1)(x)

model = Model(inp, [out1, out2])
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

metrics_callback = CoolCallback(train_data=(X, [y1,y2]), 
                                val_data=(X_val, [y1_val,y2_val]))
history = model.fit(X, [y1, y2], epochs=10, callbacks=[metrics_callback])
```